# Eliminar un elemento de una section list en SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift

**Un poco de contexto**
Estoy haciendo una app simple con CoreData y SwiftUI, tengo dos entidades territorio y usuarios, la app muestra una lista de los usuarios en sections de territorio, hago un FetchRequest tanto de usuarios como de territorios, el problema es que al borrar un usuario no se borra el adecuado, por ejemplo si borro el usuario 2 de la sección 2 se borra el 2 pero de la primera sección.

Me imagino que es el Index set el que esta pasando mal, me gustaría saber como pasar el objeto como tal para borrarlo de mi Users set.

**Aqui esta mi código:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: User.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \User.name, ascending: true)]) var users: FetchedResults<User>
    @FetchRequest(entity: Territory.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Territory.name, ascending: true)]) var territories: FetchedResults<Territory>
    @State private var showAddUser = false


       var body: some View {
           GeometryReader{ geometry in
               NavigationView {
                   ZStack {

                       List {
                           ForEach(self.territories, id: \.self) { territorie in
                            Section(header: Text(territorie.wrappedName)) {
                                ForEach(territorie.usersArray, id: \.self) { user in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: UserView(user: user)) {
                                        VStack{
                                            HStack{
                                               Text("user")
                                                Spacer()
                                                Text(user.dayLastVisit)
                                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                            }
                                            HStack {
                                                Text(user.wrappedEmoji)
                                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                                    Text("\(user.wrappedName + " " + user.wrappedLastName)")
                                                        .font(.headline)
                                                    Text(user.wrappedType)

                                                }
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }.onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
                            }
                           }



                       }
                       .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                       .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)

                       VStack {
                           Button(action:{ self.showAddRUser.toggle()}){
                               ButtonPlus(icon:"plus")}
                           .offset(x: (geometry.size.width * 0.40), y: (geometry.size.height  * 0.38))
                           .sheet(isPresented: self.$showAddUser){
                               NewUserView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
                                  }
                       }
                   }
               .navigationBarTitle("Users")
                   .navigationBarItems( trailing: HStack {
                    EditButton()
                    Button(action:{self.showAddUser.toggle()}){
                    ButtonNew(text:"Nueva")}
                    }

                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showAddUser){
                        NewUserView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
                   }
                   )

               }
           }
       }
    func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets { 
            let user = users[offset]

            //borarlo del context
            moc.delete(user)

        }
        try? moc.save()
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Preguntas**

- ¿Cómo pasar el index Set correcto?
- ¿Hay una mejor aproximación?

**Notas**

- Soy nuevo en Swift así que aprecio la ayuda, las sugerencias y las aclaraciones
- sí hizo falta más código a mas información sobre la lógica de la aplicación solo menciónalo en los comentarios y lo añadir a la pregunta.

Comment: Hola. No he revisado tu código. Pero, por la forma en que enuncias la pregunta, se trasluce un error de lógica que puede estar dando lugar al borrado accidental:
El usuario 2 de la sección 1 y el usuario 2 de la sección 2 no deben existir. Sólo puede haber un id de usuario y sólo un id de sección, ser 2 en una lista no traduce tener id 2. Y, en una relación usuarios secciones cada usuario se vincula con una o más secciones y recíprocamente, según sean las necesidades. Y los ids de relación también deben ser únicos. De ese modo se asegura univocidad al manejar el **crud**.

Comment: Al parecer debería pasar los valores a mi función de borrado como delete (at: indexSet, in: Int ) pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo pasar estos valores, por otro lado si pudiera obtener el objeto Usuario directamente también podría borrarlo, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes agregar el `tag` para identificar tu elemento, es un int y le puedes agregar el id de tu data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien al final gracias a mucha investigación en foros y la sección de Stack Overflow en inglés y la ayuda de Kevin Renskers encontré una solución añadí al `.onDelete { self.deleteItem(at: $0, in: territorie)}` para poder pasar el objeto a mi función y luego use el mismo arrayUsers de territory.

```
 func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet, in ter: Territory) {

        for offset in offsets {
             let user =  ter.usersArray[offset] 
            moc.delete(user)

        }
        try? moc.save()
    }
```